# Variable value inside a string variable in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have saved text as

```
text="Hey" + {{ student.name }}
```

I am providing both text and student to my html template page. Is there a way such that it shows the name of the student instead of the string.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Where does the provided line of code exist?

Comment: I'll be using the text as {{ text }} in a template.

Comment: I think you're missing the [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) package...